# Disable Right Click is not working on <embed> tag in Firefox, IE, but in Chrome is working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, youtube

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Right Click not Available !!!");
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlYoutube" runat="server" Style="text-align: center; height: 400px;
                width: 700px; margin-left: 100px;">
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </asp:Panel>
```

In this Literal1 control we are passing embed player like:

```
<embed src='https://www.youtube.com/v/yh2SrzCkNQA?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' id='youTubePlayer955'allowscriptaccess='never' enableJavascript ='false' allowfullscreen='false' width='700' height='400' ></embed>.
```

On chrome, disable right click is working fine, but in IE, Firefox on whole page right click disable is working but inside player disable right click is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work in IE too

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function disableSelection(e) {
        if (typeof e.onselectstart != "undefined") e.onselectstart = function() {
            return false
        };
        else if (typeof e.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") e.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
        else e.onmousedown = function() {
            return false
        };
        e.style.cursor = "default"
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        disableSelection(document.body)
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 65 || e.which == 66 || e.which == 67 || e.which == 70 || e.which == 73 || e.which == 80 || e.which == 83 || e.which == 85 || e.which == 86)) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    });
    document.keypress = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 65 || e.which == 66 || e.which == 70 || e.which == 67 || e.which == 73 || e.which == 80 || e.which == 83 || e.which == 85 || e.which == 86)) {}
        return false
    };

    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 123 || e.keyCode == 18) {
            return false
        }
    };

    document.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        var t = e || window.event;
        var n = t.target || t.srcElement;
        if (n.nodeName != "A") return false
    };
    document.ondragstart = function() {
        return false
    };
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain why this code would work. There is a lot of code here and its hard to track the answer without getting in-depth into your answer

Answer (score -3):

Try something like this:

```js
document.onmousedown=disableRightclick;
    var message="Right Click not Avaibalbe !!!";
    function disableRightclick(evt)
    {
      if(evt.button==2)
       {
         alert(message);
         return false;    
       }
    }
```

```html
<h1>Try right clicking here </h1>
<embed src='https://www.youtube.com/v/yh2SrzCkNQA?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' id='youTubePlayer955'allowscriptaccess='never' enableJavascript ='false' allowfullscreen='false' width='700' height='400' ></embed>.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your value able reply,i was trying it but by using this code also we are able to make disable right click on page, but inside the page there are <embed> player, on this <embed> player disable right click is not working,

Comment: I feel its working, can you check demo in my answer? if its not working in your page, then I would say http://jsfiddle.net/ your code

Comment: in your demo, right clicking on the embedded video works.